# Access - Checking if month and year falls between a range of dates

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a table in my database with dates (fields "Start" and "End"):

```
 Name  |   Start    |    End     |      
John   | 2014-06-30 | 2014-10-31 | 
Tom    | 2014-01-21 | 2014-05-31 |
Steve  | 2012-03-07 | 2014-11-03 |
Hana   | 2013-06-30 | 2014-05-01 |
```

Now I want to find all records with e.g. June 2013:

Expected result:

```
 Name  |   Start    |    End     |      
Steve  | 2012-03-07 | 2014-11-03 |
Hana   | 2013-06-30 | 2014-05-01 |
```

So i need to check if month and year (e.g. June 2013) falls between dates from fields "Start" and "End".

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: _Start_ and _End_ are stored as Date/Time datatype.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with converting the start and end dates to `yyyymm` integers and using those values in the WHERE clause is that the query will not be [sargable](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) and will always require a table scan, even if the corresponding date columns are indexed. On the other hand,

```sql
... WHERE [Start] < DateSerial([searchYear],[searchMonth]+1,1)
        AND [End] >=  DateSerial([searchYear],[searchMonth],1)
```

produces a sargable query.

Answer (score 2):

I approach this problem by turning the year/month into a value that counts months.  The logic looks like this:

```
where 201306 between year(start) * 100 + month(start) and
                     year(end) * 100 + month(end)
```